# Correct and RESTful way of executing actions on a server?

Tags: c++, rest, http

My application provides a REST server as a way of controlling it.
I use GET requests to retrieve various status information:

- /current_status - returns JSON object and 200 OK
- /programs - returns JSON array and 200 OK
- /configuration - returns JSON object and 200 OK
- ...

But I am not sure what request (GET, POST, etc.) should I transmit if I want to execute something on the server? 
What is the RESTful way of doing things?
Some function may fail so I need to notify a client about it which means I need to send a correct status code.

For example:

- execute task (number of task, additional parameters): `bool execute(int task, const std::string& data)` or `bool execute(int task, std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data)`
- shutdown (timeout): `bool shutdown(int timeout)`
- restart: `bool restart()`

Should GET with parameters or POST with a JSON object that describes a task?

How to handle progress updates? A client-app may ask to execute a task which takes some time to complete and I need to show it's progress on this client.
Do I need to ask the server constantly? Are there different approaches?

P.S. I am used to working with BSD sockets which means having open connection, but REST approach is connectionless, which totally breaks my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not sure what request (GET, POST, etc.) should I transmit if I want to execute something on the server? What is the RESTful way of doing things?

One thing to keep in mind is that REST/HTTP is about semantics; the client and the server exchange messages, but what the server actually does on its side is an implementation detail, so long as the implementation is consistent with the semantics of the message.

It may be good to review RFC 7231, both [section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2), which describes the common method properties, and [section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3), which describes the semantics associated with each of the HTTP methods.

But the short version is: don't use [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) methods when your intention is to change the server.

Here's how [Roy Fielding](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html) described the situation in 2002

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe. What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the sake of this definition).

Using polling in your protocol is a perfectly satisfactory way of fetching updates from the client.  WebSockets might be a viable alternative for your situation.